# 'No required module provides package' when building Go docker image

Tags: docker, go

My `Dockerfile` is below:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN go build -o /datapuller

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/datapuller" ]
```

I tried to build with `$ docker build --tag datapuller .`

But got error:

```
main.go:13:2: no required module provides package gitlab.com/mycorp/mycompany/data/datapuller/dbutil; to add it:
        go get gitlab.com/mycorp/mycompany/data/datapuller/dbutil
main.go:14:2: no required module provides package gitlab.com/mycorp/mycompany/data/datapuller/models; to add it:
        go get gitlab.com/mycorp/mycompany/data/datapuller/models
```

How to solve this, I can run directly with `go run main.go` just fine.

My `main.go`'s import is below. I think the imports caused this problem:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    client "github.com/bozd4g/go-http-client"
    "github.com/robfig/cron/v3"
    "github.com/xuri/excelize/v2"
    "gitlab.com/mycorp/mycompany/data/datapuller/dbutil"
    "gitlab.com/mycorp/mycompany/data/datapuller/models"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func main() {
...
```

Comment: Can you share `main.go`? Or at least enough of it to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I added the imports. I think that was what caused the problem.

Comment: Is `gitlab.com/mycorp/mycompany` a private repository? Are you providing go *in the image* with [the necessary credentials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-a-private-go-module-in-your-own-project)?

Comment: Yes, it is a private repository. I will try what you said.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy your source code into the image, you only copy files in the current directory

```bash
COPY *.go ./ # just the current directory's *.go, not any subdirectories
```

It's usually more common to copy in the entire host source tree, maybe using a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) to cause some of the source tree to be ignored

```bash
COPY ./ ./
```

Otherwise you need to copy the specific subdirectories you need into the image (each directory needs a separate `COPY` command)

```bash
COPY *.go ./
COPY dbutil/ dbutil/
COPY models/ models/
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the associated package needs to be pulled when building.
Docker may be missing the necessary environment variables to pull these packages.
It is recommended that you use the `go mod vendor` command,then build image

```
FROM  golang:1.18-alpine
ADD . /go/src/<project name>
WORKDIR /go/src/<project name>
RUN go build -mod=vendor -v -o /go/src/bin/main main.go
RUN rm -rf /go/src/<project name>
WORKDIR /go/src/bin
CMD ["/go/src/bin/main"]
```